# How to pass the character sequence ./abcd.sh '{\"type\":\"path\",\"key\":[]}' as an argument to a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, json

I've written a shell script, called keepAbcdRunning, whose job it is to check whether command / process 'abcd' is running and if it isn't, to start it.

keepAbcdRunning has the form:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep -x $1 > /dev/null
then echo "$1 is running"
else echo "calling $2"
$2
fi
exit 0
```

As I've written it, keepAbcdRunning needs two input arguments, `$1` is the command / process name to check and `$2` is the command needed to start abcd.

abcd itself is a script which executes an application that takes a Json formatted string as input. If I wanted to call abcd directly from a terminal, I'd call:

```
./abcd.sh '{\"type\":\"path\",\"key\":[]}'
```

However, I seem to be unable to pass the character sequence in such a way that abcd.sh is called correctly from within keepAbcdRunning....

Comment: `./abcd.sh '{\"type\":\"path\",\"key\":[]}`` why?!?!? Use `./abcd.sh -key=value -key=value` or even `./abcd.sh type=value&key=value&path=value`

Comment: Did you ever run `echo $1` within your script to see what `$1` is actually assigned?

Comment: @Thomas - yep, and I tried tons of combinations (for $2), but think finally it's cracked....

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quotes. Also, what @Rinzwind said: It'll be much, *much* better to just have the standard `--option=value` form. See: [Best way to parse command line args in Bash (StackOverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786984/best-way-to-parse-command-line-args-in-bash)

Comment: I must confess that as a complete beginner, @Rinzwind's comment went straight over my head... to further show my naivety, ultimately, the whole thing calls a matlab executable which, at least presently, can't parse arguments of the form --option=value. Would the idea be to pass the arguments in this form to Bash (keepAbcdRunning.sh) and then have that reformat them into json, ready to be passed to matlab (abcd)?

Comment: @indexfingers the 1st is a normal method when using python, perl Both have a module to read those into a variable + value. The 2nd one if a normal one for using with browsers and the GET / POST method to pass variables.

Answer (score 0):

This does it I think:
"./abcd.sh '{\\\"type\\\":\\\"path\\\"\,\\\"key\\\":[]}'"

Basically needed

\\ -> \

\" -> "

\, -> ,

Finally, whole thing needed to be in double quotes so I could have single quotes in the sequence.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063332/insert-single-quote-with-sed

Edit: This was my first time doing pretty much anything with scripting / linux / unix / ubuntu so take my advice with a pinch of salt, but I subsequently found that writing the json string to a file and then passing reference to that file to be *so* much simpler than trying to pass the string itself